# Is it possible to edit an existing user ID on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a year worth of user tracking on a site, but for some reason the Google Analytics user ID is set as `USER_ID | USER_NAME`. The problem is if the user every changes their name, their GA user ID changes with it.

Is there any way to edit all existing ids and remove the `| USER_NAME` part? I would hate to have to start over tracking all of my existing users.

Answer (score 1):

Negative. Almost all reports in Google Analytics can not be edited retroactively. Any change made will affect data going forward only.